How can I efficiently split a large .txt file into training and test sets in Python?
I have a very large .txt file (several gigabytes) that I need to split into training and test sets for a machine learning project. The usual methods of reading the entire file into memory and then splitting it are not feasible due to memory constraints. I am looking for a way to efficiently split the file without overloading memory.
I attempted to use scikit-learn for the split, but it loads the entire file into memory, which causes performance issues and is not suitable for my large dataset.

You could try reading the text file line by line. Get the count of how many lines you have and then generate a random list of indices for the test set based on your ratio. Iterating through each line, check whether the current line is inside the test indices and if it is, append it to the test text file, otherwise append to train file. This way you don't need to read the entire file at once

Thank you for the suggestion; it's indeed a good approach to read the file line by line. However, reading sequentially can make it challenging to ensure a high level of randomness in the distribution of lines between the training and test files.
To address this, I created a function that uses a buffer to read the file in chunks and splits the lines based on a random ratio. While this method improves randomness and avoids memory overload, there is still some residual sequence due to the nature of sequential reading.

I remember when I had a 12 GB Image Dataset for Object detection in an Autonomous car, I had to split it into Train and Test Dataset
I used the below code
Just add your path in Pycharm.
import os
import random

def split_large_file(input_file_path, train_file_path, test_file_path, test_ratio=0.2, buffer_size=100000):
    train_file = open(train_file_path, 'w')
    test_file = open(test_file_path, 'w')

    with open(input_file_path, 'r') as input_file:
        buffer = []
        for i, line in enumerate(input_file):
            buffer.append(line)
            if len(buffer) >= buffer_size:
                for buf_line in buffer:
                    if random.random() < test_ratio:
                        test_file.write(buf_line)
                    else:
                        train_file.write(buf_line)
                buffer = []
        
        for buf_line in buffer:
            if random.random() < test_ratio:
                test_file.write(buf_line)
            else:
                train_file.write(buf_line)

    train_file.close()
    test_file.close()

# you can see the below 
input_file_path = 'large_input_file.txt'
train_file_path = 'train_set.txt'
test_file_path = 'test_set.txt'
split_large_file(input_file_path, train_file_path, test_file_path)

Let me know if you face any error

Thank you for sharing your approach! It looks efficient. I tested it, and it does help in managing large files without overloading memory. However, even with this method, there's still a residual issue with ensuring true randomness due to the sequential reading of the file. I'm not sure if this could introduce any bias or affect the results in some way.

Here is a quick solution. There are probably some improvements that can be made. The solution assumes that each line in your .txt file constitutes one training/test sample. It will create a train.txt file and test.txt file by random selection with the desired percentage of training samples and the rest test.
import random

# Set seed for reproducibility if desired
random.seed(0)

# Get line count of file
line_count = 0
with open("large.txt", "rt") as file:
    for line in file:
        line_count += 1

# Determine number for train and test examples based on line count
train_percentage = 0.8
train_count = int(train_percentage * line_count)
test_count = line_count - train_count

# Create selector to determine which lines will be written to train or test files
selector = ["train"] * train_count + ["test"] * test_count
# Randomly shuffle
random.shuffle(selector)

# Create file names for train and test
train_fname = "train.txt"
test_fname = "test.txt"

# Create train and test files
with (
    open("large.txt", "rt") as file,
    open(train_fname, "wt") as train_file,
    open(test_fname, "wt") as test_file,
):
    for idx, line in enumerate(file):
        if selector[idx] == "train":
            train_file.write(line)
        elif selector[idx] == "test":
            test_file.write(line)
        else:
            raise Exception("Option not recognised. Check options and spelling")


Thank you for sharing your solution! I tested it and found it quite interesting. It effectively handles large files by first counting the lines and then using a shuffled selector list to distribute lines into training and test sets. This method helps ensure randomness without overloading memory. However, it still reads the dataset sequentially, which might leave some residual sequencing and potential bias, am i wrong?

@user26621042 The lines from the .txt file are read sequentially, yes, but assignment to the train and test sets is done randomly according to the selector list. This list is shuffled randomly before being used, so there is no residual sequencing and subsequent bias to worry about.
